# make a table responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

the following code is a table, i tried to make it responsive with bootstrap 3,
i added class="table" to table tag, but it didnt work. 
what should i do? what is wrong?

```
<div class="tab3_main" id="cs1">
 <table width="770" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
      <th height="50" colspan="3" align="left" scope="col">Camera</th>
     </tr>
     <tr> </tr>
     <tr> 
       <td width="135" align="left" class="td">Image Sensor:</td> 
       <td width="15" align="left" class="td1">|</td> 
       <td align="left" class="td2">1/3"&nbsp;Progressive&nbsp;Scan&nbsp;CMOS</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr> </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td width="135" align="left" class="td">Min. Illumination:</td> 
      <td width="15" align="left" class="td1">|</td> 
      <td align="left" class="td2">0.01Lux&nbsp;@(F1.2,AGC&nbsp;ON),&nbsp;0.028Lux&nbsp;@(F2.0,AGC&nbsp;ON),&nbsp;0&nbsp;Lux&nbsp;with&nbsp;IR</td> 
   </tr>
   <tr> </tr>
   <tr> 
      <td width="135" align="left" class="td">Shutter time:</td> 
      <td width="15" align="left" class="td1">|</td> 
      <td align="left" class="td2">1/3&nbsp;s&nbsp;~&nbsp;1/10,000&nbsp;s</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr> </tr>
  <tr> 
     <td width="135" align="left" class="td">Slow shutter:</td> 
     <td width="15" align="left" class="td1">|</td> 
     <td align="left" class="td2">Support</td> 
 </tr>
 <tr> </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your ".table" in ".table-responsive"

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
   ...
  </table>
</div>
```

to make a table responsive in bootstrap 3.

Comment: go to this address: http://www.farafan-market.ir/index.php/fa/hd-camera/hddvr-%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C%DA%A9-%D9%88%DB%8C%DA%98%D9%86-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%84-ds-7204hqhi-sh-detail      see the table in the bottom of the page in mobile size. swipe to right and left. as u will see the megamenu appears by swiping left to right. how should i fix this?